# Android application contact groups

Tags: android, database, sqlite, contacts

I need phone contacts to be divided into groups in my application, but only in my application so i don't want to add any groups to original phone contact database. I have made my own database to have my groups  table:

```
groups(group_id int, group_name text, message text)
```

and contacts_group table.

```
contacts_group(contact_id, group_id)
```

Now the problem i am facing: How should i create the query to get all contacts from my group (from phone contact databse).

I need something like this: Select ...DISPLAY_NAME, ...NUMBER where ..._ID in (String[] ids) while String[] ids is an array of contact_ids from contacts_group table. Is it possible to put my string array in '?' in raw query? As.. Select... where .._ID in ?, string[] ?
Thanks for help in advance
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Probelm solved. Solution:

```
public static Cursor getContactsFromGroup(String[] ids, SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER };

        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                "_ID IN (" + makePlaceHolders(ids.length) + ")", ids, null);


    }
```

where makePlacHoldes(int) puts "?" chars, as many as long is param array.
Regards